# Unable to Install Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 11

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-installer

I am unable to Install Visual Studio 2022 on my machine having windows 11.
it has 16GB of ram and 512 ssd. When i run the installer following screens comeup. any help will be appreciated.
[when i execute installer this message comes up (click here to view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1s4yT.png)

[after clicking on continue i am getting this error. (click here to view screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4sNa.png)

I tried to install visual studio 2022 and expecting it should be installed as i didnot faced this problem earlier but dont know why i am getting this error

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72994091/vs2022-installer-impossible-to-install-repair-because-of-system-numerics-and-or